# Angular preloader start after everything else has loaded

Tags: angularjs

Hopefully this is an easy answer.

I have this directive that controls the background images on the site. It rotates between images, but before it starts setting the background images, it actually preloads them. This is my code for the directive:

```
// ---
// CONTROLLERS.
// ---

.controller('BackgroundSwitcherController', ['$rootScope', 'Options', 'BackgroundSwitcherService', function ($rootScope, options, service) {
    var self = this;

    // Declare our variables
    self.model = {
        staticImage: '',
        loading: false,
        rotate: false
    };

    // On state change
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {

        // Get our data
        var data = toState.data;

        // Set our rotate flag
        self.model.rotate = options.current.rotateBackground;

        // If we are set to rotate
        if (self.model.rotate) {

            // Make a call to our service (this is called every state change, but only preloaded once)
            service.get().then(function (response) {

                // Return the images in the response
                self.model.images = response;
            });
        } else {

            // Otherwise, reset the images
            self.model.images = null;
        }

        // If we have data
        if (data) {

            // Reset our variables
            self.model.staticImage = data.backgroundImage;
            //self.model.loading = true;
        }
    });
}])

// ---
// SERVICES.
// ---

.service('BackgroundSwitcherService', ['$q', 'PreloaderService', function ($q, preloader) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.successful = false;
    this.percentLoaded = 0;

    // Get our images
    this.get = function () {

        // Our images
        var images = [
            'assets/backgrounds/Avebury Steps.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Avebury Stripe.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Avebury.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Forest Hills.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Inteface.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/New Oaklands.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Primo Delight.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Secure 3d.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Secure.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Sensation Heathers.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Sensation.jpg',
            'assets/backgrounds/Woman.jpg'
        ];

        // Create our promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Preload the images
        preloader.preloadImages(images).then(

            // Function to handle the changing of the flags when all images have loaded
            function handleResolve(imageLocations) {
                this.loading = false;
                this.successful = true;

                deferred.resolve(images);
            },

            // Function to handle any errors
            function handleReject(imageLocation) {
                this.loading = false;
                this.successful = false;

                deferred.reject();
            },

            // Function that notifies our percentage loaded flag
            function handleNotify(event) {
                this.percentLoaded = event.percent;
            }
        );

        // Return our promise
        return deferred.promise;
    };
}])

// ---
// DIRECTIVES.
// ---

.directive('backgroundSwitcher', ['$interval', function ($interval) {

    // Variables
    var target = null,
        timer = null,
        images = null,
        currentIndex = 0;

    // Function to get a random value between two numbers
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {

        // Return our random number
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    };

    var getImageIndex = function (length) {

        // Get our random index
        var index = getRandomInt(0, images.length);

        // If our index matches the current index
        if (index == currentIndex) {

            // Run again until we get a different index
            return getImageIndex(length);
        }

        // Set our current index our the new index
        currentIndex = index;

        // Return our index
        return index;
    }

    // Apply the image
    var applyImage = function () {

        // Get a random image
        var image = images[getImageIndex(images.length)];

        // Apply our image to our target
        applyStaticImage(image);
    };

    // Apply a static image
    var applyStaticImage = function (image) {

        // Apply our image to our target
        target.css('background-image', 'url(' + escape(image) + ')');
    };

    // Remove any images
    var removeImage = function () {

        // Remove our background image
        target.css('background-image', 'none');
    };

    // Start timer function
    var startTimer = function () {

        // If our timer is not running
        if (!timer || timer.$$state.status === 2) {

            // Apply our first image
            applyImage();

            // Start our timer
            timer = $interval(changeImage, 10000);
        }
    };

    // Function to change the background image
    var changeImage = function () {

        // Apply our image
        applyImage();
    };

    // Stop the timer
    var stopTimer = function () {

        // If we have started our timer
        if (timer) {

            // Stop it
            $interval.cancel(timer);
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'BackgroundSwitcherController',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

            // Assign our element to our global variable
            target = element;

            // Watch our image
            scope.$watch(function () {

                // Return our image
                return controller.model.staticImage;
            }, function (staticImage) {

                // If we have an image
                if (staticImage) {

                    // Stop our timer
                    stopTimer();

                    // Apply our static image
                    applyStaticImage(staticImage);
                } else {

                    // If we are not rotating
                    if (!controller.model.rotate) {

                        // Remove any images
                        removeImage();
                    }
                }
            })

            // Watch our rotate
            scope.$watch(function () {

                // Return our rotate flag
                return controller.model.images;
            }, function (array) {

                // Set our variable
                images = array;

                // If we have some images 
                if (images) {

                    // If we don't have a static image
                    if (!controller.model.staticImage) {

                        // Start rotating our images
                        startTimer();
                    }
                } else {

                    // Remove any images
                    removeImage();

                    // Otherwise, stop our timer
                    stopTimer();
                }
            });

            // Destroy function to cancel all timers
            element.on('$destroy', function () {

                // Stop our timer
                stopTimer();
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

and for the actual preloader I have this:

```
// ---
// SERVICES.
// ---

.factory('PreloaderService', function ($q, $rootScope) {
    function Preloader(imageLocations) {
        this.imageLocations = imageLocations;

        this.imageCount = imageLocations.length;
        this.loadCount = 0;
        this.errorCount = 0;

        this.states = {
            PENDING: 1,
            LOADING: 2,
            RESOLVED: 3,
            REJECTED: 4
        };

        this.state = this.states.PENDING;

        // When loading the images, a promise will be returned to indicate
        // when the loading has completed (and / or progressed).
        this.deferred = $q.defer();
        this.promise = this.deferred.promise;
    }


    // I reload the given images [Array] and return a promise. The promise
    // will be resolved with the array of image locations.
    Preloader.preloadImages = function (imageLocations) {
        var preloader = new Preloader(imageLocations);

        return (preloader.load());
    };

    Preloader.prototype = {
        // Best practice for 'instnceof' operator.
        constructor: Preloader,


        // ---
        // PUBLIC METHODS.
        // ---


        // I determine if the preloader has started loading images yet.
        isInitiated: function isInitiated() {
            return (this.state !== this.states.PENDING);
        },

        // I determine if the preloader has failed to load all of the images.
        isRejected: function isRejected() {
            return (this.state === this.states.REJECTED);
        },

        // I determine if the preloader has successfully loaded all of the images.
        isResolved: function isResolved() {
            return (this.state === this.states.RESOLVED);
        },

        // I initiate the preload of the images. Returns a promise.
        load: function load() {
            // If the images are already loading, return the existing promise.
            if (this.isInitiated()) {
                return (this.promise);
            }

            this.state = this.states.LOADING;

            for (var i = 0 ; i < this.imageCount ; i++) {
                this.loadImageLocation(this.imageLocations[i]);
            }

            // Return the deferred promise for the load event.
            return (this.promise);
        },


        // ---
        // PRIVATE METHODS.
        // ---


        // I handle the load-failure of the given image location.
        handleImageError: function handleImageError(imageLocation) {
            this.errorCount++;

            // If the preload action has already failed, ignore further action.
            if (this.isRejected()) {
                return;
            }

            this.state = this.states.REJECTED;

            this.deferred.reject(imageLocation);
        },


        // I handle the load-success of the given image location.
        handleImageLoad: function handleImageLoad(imageLocation) {
            this.loadCount++;

            // If the preload action has already failed, ignore further action.
            if (this.isRejected()) {
                return;
            }

            // Notify the progress of the overall deferred. This is different
            // than Resolving the deferred - you can call notify many times
            // before the ultimate resolution (or rejection) of the deferred.
            this.deferred.notify({
                percent: Math.ceil(this.loadCount / this.imageCount * 100),
                imageLocation: imageLocation
            });

            // If all of the images have loaded, we can resolve the deferred
            // value that we returned to the calling context.
            if (this.loadCount === this.imageCount) {
                this.state = this.states.RESOLVED;
                this.deferred.resolve(this.imageLocations);
            }
        },


        // I load the given image location and then wire the load / error
        // events back into the preloader instance.
        // --
        // NOTE: The load/error events trigger a $digest.
        loadImageLocation: function loadImageLocation(imageLocation) {
            var preloader = this;

            // When it comes to creating the image object, it is critical that
            // we bind the event handlers BEFORE we actually set the image
            // source. Failure to do so will prevent the events from proper
            // triggering in some browsers.
            var image = angular.element(new Image());

            image.bind('load', function (event) {
                // Since the load event is asynchronous, we have to
                // tell AngularJS that something changed.
                $rootScope.$apply(
                    function () {
                        preloader.handleImageLoad(event.target.src);

                        // Clean up object reference to help with the
                        // garbage collection in the closure.
                        preloader = image = event = null;
                    }
                );

            }).bind('error', function (event) {
                // Since the load event is asynchronous, we have to
                // tell AngularJS that something changed.
                $rootScope.$apply(
                    function () {

                        preloader.handleImageError(event.target.src);

                        // Clean up object reference to help with the
                        // garbage collection in the closure.
                        preloader = image = event = null;
                    }
                );

            }).prop('src', imageLocation);
        }
    };

    // Return the factory instance.
    return (Preloader);
});
```

Now, when I use this directive all my other images / font awesome icons pause before they load. It causes an issue because the font awesome icons actually briefly show a rectangular box before fully loading and the profile image is blank until loaded.
If I remove my directive from my HTML everything loads fine.

Now I realise that this is happening because it has to load an array of images for the background switcher, so what I would like to do is to not start the preloading until everything else has loaded first.

Can someone tell me if there is a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a plunkr?